# php: Declare arguments type of a Function

Tags: php, function, arguments

I'm trying to make a function with declared argument types, to quickly check if they are in the right format, but when it returns a string I this error:

`Catchable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to myfunction() must be an instance of string, string given, called in path_to_file on line 69 and defined in path_to_file on line 49`

Example

```
function myfunction( array $ARRAY, string $STRING, int $INTEGER ) { 
    return "Args format correct"; 
}
myfunction(array("1",'2','3','4'), "test" , 1234);
```

Where is the mistake?

Comment: You can't hint of for scalar values.

Comment: Now you can, just use PHP 7.0 http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration

Answer (score 62, accepted):

According to [the PHP5 documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration):

> Type Hints can only be of the object and array (since PHP 5.1) type. Traditional type hinting with int and string isn't supported.

Since `string` and `int` are not classes, you can't "type-hint" them in your function.

As of PHP 7.0 declaring argument type as string, int, float, bool is supported.

Comment: this answer is outdated, see http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration

Comment: What if I have a class `Person` and I want to accept an array of `Person` as parameter for my function? How can I do that?

Answer (score 37):

This maybe useful for anyone who see this post since the availability of PHP 7

With PHP 7, its now possible to declare types. You can refer the following link for more information.

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration

```
function(string $name, bool $is_admin) {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: is it always recommended to include parameter type?

Comment: `boolean` as type declaration will check for `instanceof boolean` instead of checking for a boolean value. The correct type declaration is `bool`. e.g. `function a(value: boolean); a(true)` will fail.

Comment: What about the syntax of the return type of this function?

Comment: @AlexLacayo I think it's good practice. PHP has always been very lenient when it comes to variable type and assigment. But being too open will inevitably lead to head scratching bug one day.
Return type is declared using a colon, followed by return type. For example : function foo() : int { return 0; }

Comment: Shouldn't it be `bool` instead of `boolean` according to https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php?

Comment: @mehov yes, type support have become more robust in PHP since I answered it in 2017 when the documentation had boolean instead of bool.  I will update the answer so it helps others who see it now.

Answer (score 5):

You can do something like this which has always worked for me

for string

```
function setData($Name=""){ }
```

this forces the name to be a string, it doesn't check if its a string

for numeric values

```
function setData($age=0){ }
```

this forces the age to be a number, if a string is passed, the value will be 0

for array values , there are two variation

```
function setData(array $data){ }
```

if an array is not passed, it would throw an error

```
function setData($data=array()){ }
```

This would pass an empty array of no value is given for `$data`

Comment: Specifying default values for arguments is an important technique but shouldn't be equated with type hinting. For example, it's not entirely true that specifying `func( $x=0 )` forces the value of `$x` to be a number. Rather, if your function always processes the value of `$x` as a number throughout, then by coincidence it works out. Actually if you pass in a string that happens to be parsable as a number, then it will be processed that way. `func( '5' )` would cheerfully use 5 as the integer value. A string that isn't parsable is interpreted as zero, so your 0 default works by coincidence.

Answer (score 5):

According to [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration), you can do that for `array` on **PHP 5.1** and beyond and for `string` and `int` types on **PHP 7** and beyond. Take a look:

- `Class/interface name`    The parameter must be an instanceof the given class or interface name.  ***PHP 5.0.0***
- `self`    The parameter must be an instanceof the same class as the one the method is defined on. This can only be used on class and instance methods.    ***PHP 5.0.0***
- > `array` The parameter must be an array. ***PHP 5.1.0***
- `callable`    The parameter must be a valid callable. ***PHP 5.4.0***
- `bool`    The parameter must be a boolean value.  ***PHP 7.0.0***
- `float`   The parameter must be a floating point number.  ***PHP 7.0.0***
- > `int`   The parameter must be an integer.   ***PHP 7.0.0***
- > `string`    The parameter must be a string. ***PHP 7.0.0***
- `iterable`    The parameter must be either an array or an instanceof Traversable. ***PHP 7.1.0***

Comment: You can use array as hint since PHP 5.1.0

Comment: Of course, you're right, I wrote it right myself after writing wrong hehe.

Answer (score 1):

`string`, `int` and other built-in types are not **classes**, in argument you specify **class**, of the argument. The only supported built-in type to be put there is `array`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot define type as `string` and `int`. PHP "does not know" what they are.

Comment: It does know the types, [it just doesn’t care](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Strong_and_weak_typing).

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using PHP 7.x or need some complex argument validations (like "an array or \Traversable" because you can traverse arrays but they are primitive types and don't implement the \Traversable interface) you can use [args](https://github.com/ihor/Nspl#nsplargs) module from [Non-standard PHP library (NSPL)](https://github.com/ihor/Nspl).

```
use const \nspl\args\numeric;
use function \nspl\args\expects;

function sqr($x)
{
    expects(numeric, $x);
    return $x * $x;
}

sqr('hello world');
```

Outputs:

```
InvalidArgumentException: Argument 1 passed to sqr() must be numeric, string given in /path/to/example.php on line 17

Call Stack:
    0.0002     230304   1. {main}() /path/to/example.php:0
    0.0023     556800   2. sqr() /path/to/example.php:17
```

Answer (score 0):

when I need use Type Hints, I do this:

```
<?php 
declare(strict_types=1);
```

Comment: Please add more description regarding your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Type declared variable arguments from PHP7

```php
<?php
function total_intervals($unit, DateInterval ...$intervals) {
    $time = 0;
    foreach ($intervals as $interval) {
        $time += $interval->$unit;
    }
    return $time;
}

$a = new DateInterval('P1D');
$b = new DateInterval('P2D');
echo total_intervals('d', $a, $b).' days';

// This will fail, since null isn't a DateInterval object.
echo total_intervals('d', null);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#example-164